# Facebook Canvas/Tab app, fb_sig_profile_id, fb_sig_app_id

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-canvas

With the changes for Facebook Apps coming on October 1st, I am having trouble confirming that our Canvas/Tab app will/will not work as expected.

When a user first loads the tab with the app, I'm expecting facebook to send me parameters of "fb_sig_profile_id" (which I believe should be the ID of the Page) and "fb_sig_app_id" (the ID of the APP).

I DO NOT need/want to authenticate users or access UserData/Graph etc.  I am simply displaying content on my end based on these parameters.

If this is no longer the case and Facebook is not going to be sending me these parameters, can someone point me in the direction of how I can get this data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When building *Apps On Facebook* kind of apps, Facebook will send a [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which will contain the data you need:

> When a user navigates to the Facebook Page, they will see your Page
>   Tab added in the next available tab position. Broadly, a Page Tab is
>   loaded in exactly the same way as a Canvas Page. Read more about this
>   in the Canvas Tutorial. When a user selects your Page Tab, **you will
>   receive the `signed_request` parameter with one additional parameter,
>   `page`**. This parameter contains a JSON object with an `id` (the page id of
>   the current page), `admin` (if the user is a admin of the page), and
>   `liked` (if the user has liked the page). As with a Canvas Page, you
>   will not receive all the user information accessible to your app in
>   the `signed_request` until the user authorizes your app.

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/).